# Implicit declaration of function 'FillOutASBDForLPCM' is invalid in C99

Tags: ios, objective-c, c99

When implementing the predefined inline C++ method, I am getting

> Implicit declaration of function 'FillOutASBDForLPCM' is invalid in
> C99

error. Please help me what i made the mistake or Do i import or add anything to access C++ method. I added this function, whenever I try to compile I am getting error.

```
void Convert()
{
    //File URLs
    CFURLRef micUrl = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(NULL, (CFStringRef)kMicFilePath, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);
    CFURLRef speakerUrl = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(NULL, (CFStringRef)kSpeakerFilePath, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);
    CFURLRef mixUrl = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(NULL, (CFStringRef)kResultFilePath, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);

    ExtAudioFileRef micFile = NULL;
    ExtAudioFileRef speakerFile = NULL;
    ExtAudioFileRef mixFile = NULL;

    //Opening input files (speaker and mic)
    ExtAudioFileOpenURL(micUrl, &micFile);
    ExtAudioFileOpenURL(speakerUrl, &speakerFile);
//Reading input file audio format (mono LPCM)
    AudioStreamBasicDescription inputFormat, outputFormat;
    UInt32 descSize = sizeof(inputFormat);
    ExtAudioFileGetProperty(micFile, kExtAudioFileProperty_FileDataFormat, &descSize, &inputFormat);
    int sampleSize = inputFormat.mBytesPerFrame;

    //Filling input stream format for output file (stereo LPCM)
    FillOutASBDForLPCM(inputFormat, inputFormat.mSampleRate, 2, inputFormat.mBitsPerChannel, inputFormat.mBitsPerChannel, true, false, false);
    

    //Filling output file audio format (AAC)
    memset(&outputFormat, 0, sizeof(outputFormat));
    outputFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC;
    outputFormat.mSampleRate = 8000;
    outputFormat.mFormatFlags = kMPEG4Object_AAC_Main;
    outputFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
//Opening output file
    ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL(mixUrl, kAudioFileM4AType, &outputFormat, NULL, kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile, &mixFile);
    ExtAudioFileSetProperty(mixFile, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat, sizeof(inputFormat), &inputFormat);

    //Freeing URLs
    CFRelease(micUrl);
    CFRelease(speakerUrl);
    CFRelease(mixUrl);

    //Setting up audio buffers
    int bufferSizeInSamples = 64 * 1024;

    AudioBufferList micBuffer;
    micBuffer.mNumberBuffers = 1;
    micBuffer.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;
    micBuffer.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = sampleSize * bufferSizeInSamples;
    micBuffer.mBuffers[0].mData = malloc(micBuffer.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize);

    AudioBufferList speakerBuffer;
    speakerBuffer.mNumberBuffers = 1;
    speakerBuffer.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;
    speakerBuffer.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = sampleSize * bufferSizeInSamples;
    speakerBuffer.mBuffers[0].mData = malloc(speakerBuffer.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize);

    AudioBufferList mixBuffer;
    mixBuffer.mNumberBuffers = 1;
    mixBuffer.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 2;
    mixBuffer.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = sampleSize * bufferSizeInSamples * 2;
    mixBuffer.mBuffers[0].mData = malloc(mixBuffer.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize);

    //Converting
    while (true)
    {
        //Reading data from input files
        UInt32 framesToRead = bufferSizeInSamples;
        ExtAudioFileRead(micFile, &framesToRead, &micBuffer);
        ExtAudioFileRead(speakerFile, &framesToRead, &speakerBuffer);
        if (framesToRead == 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        //Building interleaved stereo buffer - left channel is mic, right - speaker
        for (int i = 0; i < framesToRead; i++)
        {
            memcpy((char*)mixBuffer.mBuffers[0].mData + i * sampleSize * 2, (char*)micBuffer.mBuffers[0].mData + i * sampleSize, sampleSize);
            memcpy((char*)mixBuffer.mBuffers[0].mData + i * sampleSize * 2 + sampleSize, (char*)speakerBuffer.mBuffers[0].mData + i * sampleSize, sampleSize);
        }

        //Writing to output file - LPCM will be converted to AAC
        ExtAudioFileWrite(mixFile, framesToRead, &mixBuffer);
    }

    //Closing files
    ExtAudioFileDispose(micFile);
    ExtAudioFileDispose(speakerFile);
    ExtAudioFileDispose(mixFile);

    //Freeing audio buffers
    free(micBuffer.mBuffers[0].mData);
    free(speakerBuffer.mBuffers[0].mData);
    free(mixBuffer.mBuffers[0].mData);
}
```

Comment: Where is the function declared/defined? If it's C++, do you set corresponding file extension for the file (`.cpp` or `.mm`)? Or how do you make Clang aware of the language?

Comment: Thanks for the reply https://stackoverflow.com/users/5690248/the-dreams-wind.
But it is a predefined inline c++ function. it is in 
 the file:  CoreAudioBaseTypes.h  framework: CoreAudioTypes.framework
If I add a c++ header. Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have this function included from `CoreAudio` framework:

```objc
#import <CoreAudio/CoreAudio.h>
```

You merely need to inform the compiler that the code takes C++ code. Provided it's a mixed with Objective-C code file, you apparently want it to be of `.mm` format OR need to specify the language explicitly when compiling the file with use of `-ObjC++` flag (in addition to other parameters):

```
% clang -ObjC++ MyFile.m
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to compile both objective-c and c++ without any files. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @Ramkumar I'm not talking about any new files, you should change the source file your code is in. (E.g. if the code you provided is in a file named `MyFile.m` you are supposed to rename it in way it has corresponding extension: `MyFile.mm`)